# Component Cart not re-rendering when element in context changes

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I've got a problem here hope someone can find it:

I have this simple cart modal component:

```js
import Modal from 'react-modal';

import { useContext } from 'react';
import { ProductContext } from '../context/ProductContext';
import { CartProduct } from './CartProduct';

Modal.setAppElement('#root');

export const CartModal = () => {

  const { cartIsOpen, cart } = useContext( ProductContext );

  return (
    <Modal
      isOpen={cartIsOpen}
    >
      <h3>Shopping Cart</h3>
      <hr></hr>

      {
        cart.map( cartProduct => {
          return <CartProduct key={`cart-${cartProduct.id}`} {...cartProduct}/>
        })
      }
    </Modal>
  );

}
```

Inside that cart component I have some elements (products)

```js
import { useContext } from "react";
import { ProductContext } from "../context/ProductContext";

export const CartProduct = ({title, price, thumbnail, quantity, id}) => {

  const { setCart, cart } = useContext( ProductContext );

  const changeQuantity = (operation) => {
    const cartProduct = cart.find(cartProduct => {
      return cartProduct.id === id
    })

    switch (operation) {
      case 'sum':
        cartProduct.quantity ++;
        break;
      case 'substract':
        if (cartProduct.quantity === 1) return 
        cartProduct.quantity --;

        break;
    }

    const cartIndex = cart.findIndex(cartProduct => {
      return cartProduct.id === id;
    })

    cart[cartIndex] = cartProduct;

    setCart(cart);
  }

  return (
    <div className="card cart-product mt-1">
      <div className="card-body">
        <div className='d-flex'>

          <div className="product-image">
            <img src={thumbnail} alt={title} />
          </div>

          <div className="product-info">
            <h5 className="card-title">{title}</h5>
            <p className="card-text">{price} €</p>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div className="buttons d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mt-3">
          <a onClick={() => {changeQuantity('substract')}} className="btn btn-primary">-</a>
          <span>{quantity}</span>
          <a onClick={() => {changeQuantity('sum')}} className="btn btn-primary">+</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And here we go, when I try to update the quantity with the function changeQuantity I can see with react devtools that the quantity is changing but the component won't re-render:

[image]

does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: You’re modifying state directly.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you mean. I'm still a newbie :(

Comment: Okey Done, you gave me the clue. I needed to create a copy of the cart element so the component could update.